# Is an unramified extension of $Q_p$ complete w.r.t. the extension of the p-adic norm?

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, ramification

I'm studying for a course in number theory and I have seen that:

- $\Bbb Q_p$ is complete w.r.t. the $p$-adic norm
- $\Bbb Q_p^{unram}$, the union of all unramified extensions of $\Bbb Q_p$, is not complete

But what if we take a single unramified extension? Is it complete?
So, can we use Hensel's lemma to lift roots?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3):

Every finite extension of $\Bbb Q_p$ is complete with respect to the extended
norm. In general infinite algebraic extensions won't be.

In your example of $\Bbb Q_p^{\textrm{unram}}$ I would try looking at
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty p^n \zeta_n$, where $\zeta_n$ is a root of unity in the degree
$2^n$ unramified extension of $\Bbb Q_p$ but not in any smaller extension.
Can you prove that this series doesn't converge
 in $\Bbb Q_p^{\textrm{unram}}$? If it did, it would converge to some element
of a finite extension of $\Bbb Q_p$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: “In general infinite algebraic extensions won't be.” Indeed, looks to me that any infinite extension of $\Bbb Q_p$ will fail to be complete.